# Is it possible to separate part of a joined mesh corresponding to it's assigned material?

Tags: mesh, vertices

So like say I had a single mesh, that had multiple materials assigned to it, like a character or something, I want too be able to separate the vertices that have the correspond material assigned to them into their own mesh. I know you can use the "Selection" method by selecting your vertices in edit mode and then pressing "P", then click "Selection" and it separates into it's own mesh, but the problem is I have to select the correct vertices, it's not so easy when you are trying to do that when the character has so many subdivisions. So is there a way I can just separate the mesh that corresponds to the material it's assigned to?

Answer (score 2):

Select a vertex/edge/face that has the material you want to separate, then press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose the *Material* option. This will separate any faces that have that material into a new object, and you only have to select one.

Comment: In edit mode, you can deselect all, then under the material list you can select the  mesh that is using the material.